# assign ip to vmware player

Tags: vmware

I have a dedicated windows server 2008

I'm installed vmware player 5 on it and ubuntu 10.04 in vwmare
now i buyed a new ip

ip is :

IP: 78.157.60.141

private: 192.168.150.50

I want to set this ip to vwmare

my question is how I must do that ?

i don't have any acsess to defualt gateway in adress 192.168.150.1

hosting tell to me i most set the ip of vmware in range of this private ip

when i assign the ip with this command

```
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- stop nat
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- stop dhcp
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- set vnet vmnet8 mask 255.255.255.0 
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- set vnet vmnet8 addr 192.168.150.0 
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- update dhcp vmnet8
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- update nat vmnet8
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- update adapter vmnet8 
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- start dhcp
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- start nat
start /wait vnetlib.exe -- stop dhcp
```

And then I set the network of vmware player in net mode

now ubuntu auth1 cannot connect and ubuntu is in offline mode

how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to VMware player setting -> In Network Adapter change from NAT to Bridged. Then you can set your IP. Now your IP appears to outside network. Hope that will solve your issue

Comment: thanks, but if i set to bridge and set ip , ubuntu go offline and don't have acsess to internet
ps : i has edited /etc/network/interfaces and setted ip in it

Comment: Can you please describe how is your windows server 2008 connected to Internet?

Comment: it's a server i buying it , and i don't have a clear view of how it's connected
in its localarea connection has a gateway : 192.168.172.1
and two ip : 192.168.172.50 and 51

Comment: I assume the VMPlayer you have hosted has Internet? And you can access 192.168.150.50 from your host machine?

Comment: no in first install i had acsess , but after change ip not acsess to that

Comment: So I think you need to fix that first and then worry about your VM

Comment: when with vnetlib.exe set ip to 10.11.12.0 and network of vmware is on nat . the vmware is connected and i can see that from server